# Solving equation concerning CDF of Normal random variable

Tags: normal-distribution

Let $Y \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and $F_Y(y)$ denote its cummulative distribution function.

Any hint to solve the equation below for unknown $x$, known constant $a,b,c$?

$$1-F_Y\left(a\sqrt{x}+bx\right) = cF_Y(bx)$$

I know that $0 < c, x <1$ and $a,b$ have values assuring the equation has solution (the solution can be found by using exhaustive search in [0,1] but I expect an analytical solution).

I got stuck because the CDF involves integral. If there were only one CDF, it should be ok with Q-function. But with two of them, I don't know where to start.

Comment: "I expect an analytical solution" Unless if $c=1$, do not expect too much...

Comment: @Did could you please show me how to solve the equation if $c=1$?

Comment: Well, for every $y$, $P(Y\leqslant y)=1-P(Y\leqslant 2\mu-y)$, hence, if $c=1$, one simply must solve $$a\sqrt x+bx=2\mu-bx$$